# I'm getting Exception : PlatformException (PlatformException(100, Failed read arguments, null, null))

Tags: android, flutter, exception, background-service

I tried to build a flutter app. This exception only occurs when building to android app.
this problem is related to flutter_background_service package. I'm already refer to this issue. https://github.com/ekasetiawans/flutter_background_service/issues/226
In this article, they have exactly same issue.
But I can not downgrade the package version. (because it's not my own project)
I tried to change version of flutter, Kotlin and java ..but these are useless..
I just want to know about what means exception code 100.

[error code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl2GV.png)

Comment: I fixed it! flutter_background_service_android: 2.5.4 => 2.5.0 !
2.5.4 is not support android 12.

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is stumbling on this (as I did today), the solution I found was to add the correct permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Here's what I added:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
```